# Change certain numbers in string

Tags: javascript

I've got a string which at times contains css font sizes. 
For example:

```
str = '<span style="font-size: 200px;white-space:nowrap;">Text</span>
<br><span style="color:#555555;font-size:10px;">Some otherText</span>';
```

I need to change all the font sizes by multiplying them all by a set ratio of for example 1.5

```
var ratio = 1.5;
```

Search and replace is not my strong suit. How do I search the string for all font sizes and then do the math on each number?

So that the above string with this ratio will become:

```
str = '<span style="font-size: 300px;white-space:nowrap;">Text</span>
<br><span style="color:#555555;font-size:15px;">Some otherText</span>';
```

Comment: You can use a RegExp where " : 0000px" if you are sure to use one unit "px" then get all the numbers out of the string and parse them.

Comment: Don't hack at raw HTML with JavaScript. The DOM is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that have that as a string and there is not a better way (if this came from `innerHTML` or so, you're doin' it wrong), then...

```
var fauxDocFrag = document.createElement("div");
var elements, i, len;

fauxDocFrag.innerHTML = str;

elements = fauxDocFrag.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].style.fontSize = (parseInt(elements[i].style.fontSize) * 1.5)
                                 + "px";
}

str = fauxDocFrag.innerHTML;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vK59Z/).

If your browser doesn't suck...

```
var fauxDocFrag = document.createElement("div");

fauxDocFrag.innerHTML = str;

[].forEach.call(fauxDocFrag.getElementsByTagName("*"), function(element) {
     element.style.fontSize = (parseInt(elements.style.fontSize) * 1.5)
                              + "px";
});

str = fauxDocFrag.innerHTML;
```

If any of the declarations were not in the `style` attribute, you could use `getComputedStyle()`.

I didn't use a real `documentFragment`, because it doesn't support the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: Some say that it is always good to pass base (radix) argument to `parseInt`.

Comment: @VisioN My browser always strips leading `0`s when reading the `fontSize` property, and any hexadecimal looking value returns an empty string.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks Alex - what is the purpose of creating the div? And is this method better than the one Nick suggested?

Comment: @JohnSmith The advantage of this one is that it won't mangle things that look like CSS values which are text nodes of the actual document. The `div`'s purpose is explained by its variable name and the last sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alex is right, there's probably a much better way, but to answer your question with a string replacing answer:

```
str = str.replace(/(\d+)px/g, function (fullStr, pixels) {
  return (pixels * 1.5) + 'px';
});
```

Comment: Sheesh, when did you get more rep than me, huh? I'm taking back that upvote.

Comment: Someone had to pick up the slack since you've been gone :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` method of `String` objects, and specify a function as the replacement value.

```
str.replace(/font-size:\s*(\d*)/g,
            function (line, p1) { return ratio * parseInt(p1) })
```

Comment: I considered this, but it doesn't *know* about `style` attributes. If I included this as a substring in a text node, it'd be mangled.